# Failed to read key <key> from store ".../keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to build a signed APK using an existing keystore file, so that I can update an app that is already in the Play Store, however gradle seems unable to recognise the password for the keyfile.

Usually we build our app via Bitrise, but it's been having issues lately, so I have been attempting to build it using `./gradlew assembleRelease` and Android Studio (which uses the same command to create a signed APK).

Everything seems fine, until gradle gets to the `:app:packageRelease` step.

The full error is: `com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key <alias> from store "/Users/admin/Documents/projects/<app>/android/app/<keyfile>.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

I'm fairly certain it's an issue with the password to the keystore file, because when I try `keytool -list -keystore <app>.jks` I am prompted for the password which I then enter, and am given a very similar error: `keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file('<app>.jks')
                storePassword '<store_password>'
                keyAlias '<alias>'
                keyPassword '<key_password>'
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
```

To make sure it is a keystore file issue, I have also generated a new keystore file, however using the extension `.keystore`, and the app builds just fine.

I have been looking for an entire day at this issue now with no luck, none of the similar questions are helping unfortunately. I would be very grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: `password was incorrect` Are you sure you have the right password?

Comment: I'm as certain as I can be - I didn't set up the initial keystore file but the guy who did assures me the password is correct. I think Bitrise uses Linux, while I'm on Mac OS. Could this be a possible cause?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, command line fails, however Android Studio signs the app absolutely fine when I copy/paste the password in

Answer (score 2):

## For the folks experiencing similar errors:

Make Sure that in file **key.properties is no whitespace after the password** entries. I had trouble building my appbundle because there was a bit of whitespace (I think from autoformat or something).

I hope this fixes your problems.